# Flutter Listview Not filter to the search result

Tags: flutter, list

I created an appbar search that takes users' names and sends them to the profile page . the problem is listview is not updating when I enter the user name (list order not changing)
when I type different name that isn't int the list it shows empty but when I type a name that in list view it shows me the first item which don't same

this is my search delegate class

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (query == "") {
            close(context, null);
          } else {
            query = query = '';
          }
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
      ),
    ];
  }

// second overwrite to pop out of search menu
  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    );
  }

// third overwrite to show query result
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> matchQuery = [];
    for (var documentName in data!) {
      if (documentName.recipientName!.contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
        matchQuery.add(documentName.recipientName.toString());
      }
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: matchQuery.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              UtilFunctions.navigateTo(context,
                  MainScreen(patientid: data![index].senderId.toString()));

              query = "";
            },
            child: ProfileList(
              patientid: data![index].senderId.toString(),
              phn: data![index].phn.toString(),
              sharedDate: data![index].sharedDate.toString(),
              username: data![index].senderName.toString(),
            ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> matchQuery = [];
    for (var document in data!) {
      if (document.senderName!.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
        matchQuery.add(document.senderName.toString());
      }
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: matchQuery.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              close(context, null);
              query = "";
              UtilFunctions.navigateTo(context,
                  MainScreen(patientid: data![index].senderId.toString()));
            },
            child: ProfileList(
              patientid: data![index].senderId.toString(),
              phn: data![index].phn.toString(),
              sharedDate: data![index].sharedDate.toString(),
              username: data![index].senderName.toString(),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

you can check my video here [listview no updating](https://youtube.com/shorts/oggIpdJNJV4?feature=share)

Answer (score -1):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class SearchBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBarWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchBarWidget> createState() => _SearchBarWidgetState();
}

class _SearchBarWidgetState extends State<SearchBarWidget> {
  List<String> list = ["Arshad", "khan", "junaid", "Babar", "Tariq", "Mobile"];
  String search = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              search = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (search.isEmpty) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(list[index]),
            );
          }
          if (list[index].toLowerCase().contains(search)) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(list[index]),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use idea.
Note: remove the for loop and and write the if condition in ListView.builder